# Is the story of Momonosuke, the boy who transformed into a dragon, based on any folklore in real life?

Tags: one-piece

During the Punk Hazard arc, the boy Momonosuke transformed into a dragon. The story of a boy who turned into a dragon sounds really familiar to me for some reason. I believe I might have heard it somewhere before as some sort of tale, or maybe even as a part of some myth. I have been searching quite a bit to find something similar, but I couldn't find anything.

So is the story of Momonosuke, the boy who transformed into a dragon, based on anything?

Comment: There are many folktales in Asian culture about dragons, many of them involving dragons that take the form of humans. In recent memory, there's spirited away that has something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of cartoons/anime/movies where a boy transforms into a dragon.

- [*American Dragon: Jake Long*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Dragon:_Jake_Long), an American cartoon.
- [*The Chronicles of Narnia: The Voyage of the Dawn Treader*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Narnia:_The_Voyage_of_the_Dawn_Treader), a movie based on [the novel with same title](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Voyage_of_the_Dawn_Treader), which has [a boy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eustace_Scrubb) who turns to a dragon.
- [*Legend of the Dragon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_the_Dragon_%28TV_series%29), another cartoon.
- [Fafnir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fafnir), a legend connected to the idea of a person turning into a dragon:

  > In Norse mythology, Fáfnir (Old Norse and Icelandic) or Frænir was a son of the dwarf king Hreidmar and brother of Regin and Ótr. After being affected by the curse of Andvari's ring and gold, Fafnir became a dragon and was slain by Sigurd.
- A Chinese legend of [carp turning into dragon after passing through the Dragon Gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_carp#In_Chinese_culture).

Comment: Oh.. i know all of these . Would not suprise me if thats indeed the case.